# ancova is not printing as a model but a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to export my ancova using `stargazer`, but once I assign the ancova it prints as a data frame instead of a model, please see my code below:

```
iris

irs_ancova <- Anova(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length*Petal.Width, data = iris ))

summary(irs_ancova)
```

output:

```
Sum Sq              Df            F value           Pr(>F)         
 Min.   : 0.6443   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   : 4.791   Min.   :0.0000000  
 1st Qu.: 3.3442   1st Qu.:  1.00   1st Qu.:18.173   1st Qu.:0.0000000  
 Median : 7.0892   Median :  1.00   Median :31.556   Median :0.0000001  
 Mean   : 8.6148   Mean   : 37.25   Mean   :36.736   Mean   :0.0100674  
 3rd Qu.:12.3598   3rd Qu.: 37.25   3rd Qu.:52.709   3rd Qu.:0.0151011  
 Max.   :19.6366   Max.   :146.00   Max.   :73.862   Max.   :0.0302022  
                                    NA's   :1        NA's   :1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. You called `summary`, and it printed the summary output. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: Use `print(irs_ancova)` or just `irs_ancova`

Comment: `car::Anova` just returns a data frame, maybe you are wanting `stats::aov` or `stats::manova` or something else which has a `summary` method